# User authentication in Elasticsearch without third party tools

Tags: security, authentication, elasticsearch

Is there any way to do user authentication without any third-party tools; just need to prevent access with username and password.

Comment: Can you add precisions ? How do you want to be authenticated ? Do you try [xPack](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-xpack.html) ?

Comment: I do not want an x-pack as it is 30 days free and then paid. I am looking for free tools. 
I just want to be authenticated with a simple username and password.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible and you can use X-Pack, which is an Elastic Stack extension that provides security. By default, when you install Elasticsearch, X-Pack is installed with a 30-day trial. 
here the docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-security.html

If you are looking for something open-source opendistro for elasticsearch provides the same services for free and has support for Active Directory, LDAP, Kerberos, SAML, and OpenID Connect, here the docs: https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/security-configuration/

If you wish you can install the OSS version of elasticsearch, which includes only Apache 2.0 licensed code (here: https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss-7.6.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz) and then install the standalone plugin for security with this command:

```
`sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://d3g5vo6xdbdb9a.cloudfront.net/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/opendistro-security/opendistro_security-`1.4.0.0.zip
```

as described here:

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/install/plugins/#security

Let me know if you need help for configure authentication!
Good luck!

Comment: I am getting error for the different version support: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin [opendistro_security] was built for Elasticsearch version 6.6.2 but some other version is running.

Answer (score 1):

The basic auth part if free starting from Elasticsearch 6.8. However, you'll need to buy X-Pack for advanced stuff like LDAP Authn / Authz.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free